# Filling NAs based on existing values

Tags: r, replace, na

I have created a tibble that I merged from many CSVs.
Now I have the issue that in some of the CSVs names are missing but they all have an identifier, but I would like to fill up the missing names. After merging this looks like this, if my description is unclear:

| Identifier | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 1 | NA |
| 2 | NA |
| 2 | NA |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | b |

How can I fill the NAs in the names when according to the identifier. Such that 1 would always get the a, 2 always the b because that's know already? Since there are around 50 different identifiers, specifying it by hand is very time consuming.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `fill` to replace the NA elements by adjacent non-NA elements grouped by 'Identifier'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   group_by(Identifier) %>%
   fill(Name, .direction = "downup") %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do I actually have to group and ungroup?

Comment: @QuestJonas suppose there is a NA value at the beginning of row in a new identifier, fill will change the NA to previous non-NA from the previous identifier.  group by will prevent that.  the `ungroup` at the end removes the grouping attribute so that you may do some transformations without the grouping